# Use tsconfig.json in sub-directories of app folder in Angular build/ ng-build

Tags: angular, typescript, tsconfig

I'm trying to use multiple tsconfig.json files in our angular project specifically to allow
strictNullChecks to be true in specific folders (until eventually all the errors are fixed and we can switch it on globally).

I can get this functionality to work running tsc command using *"references"* in the root tsconfig file and *extends* in the subfolder(s).

However this doesn't work whilst running ng-build and the build simply passes.

Anyone managed to get this to work or at least any idea why it's not working in this context?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should use an approach similar to nx, splitting your project in a main project with multiple sub-projects (libs), and reference them in `angular.json` as separated projects, something like this:

```json
{
   "$schema": "./node_modules/nx/schemas/workspace-schema.json",
   ...
   "projects": {
     "project-1": "libs/project-1",
   }
}
```

you can see workspace docs for more info: https://angular.io/guide/file-structure

This doesn't answer exactly to your question, but imho it's a more clean way to tackle the problem, because you could address, for example, also specific tsconfig.json for tests.

Hope it could help

Comment: This is not the answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems this may not be possible.

I decided to add the check to our build instead as a workaround.